# How to find bounds on the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

Given this matrix

$M=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & m-1 & 2 & n-1\\
1 & m-2& 1 & n-1\\
2 & m-1 & 0 & 2(n-1)\\
1 & m-1 & 2 & 2(n-2)\end{bmatrix},$ show that if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are two negative eigenvalues of $M$,  then $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<-3$.
Alsoo $m,n\ge 4$ are integers.

Using Gershgorin circles theorem, the eigenvalues would lie in the intervals $B(0,m+n)$, $B(m-2,n-1)$, $B(0,2n+m-1)$,$ B(2n-4,m+2)$ where $B(x,y)$ denotes the interval with centre $x$ and radius $y$.
But it's not helping to find the required bound?

Does there exist any theorem/trick to find a better upper bound of the sum of two negative eigenvalues of a matrix?

If someone can help, I will be grateful.

Comment: What are the constraints on $m$ and $n$? Are they integers? non-negative (or positive) integers?

Comment: @gmvh; I have edited it

Comment: If this is still relevant, you can use Tarski-Seidenberg to get a complete answer for real $m,n$ in any specified range. Together with an explicit computation for small integer values of $m,n$, this should probably suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to accurately calculate the eigenvalues in perturbation theory, as follows:

I perform a similarity transformation on the matrix $M$, given by $M'=S^{-1}MS$ with

<sub>$$S=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & \frac{-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 m} & \frac{\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 m} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 m} & \frac{\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 m} \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$</sub>

The matrix $M'$ has the same eigenvalues as $M$ and is given by
$M'=M_0+M_1$, with

<sub>$$M_0=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m+2 n\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m+2 n\right) \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$M_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-3\right) & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+\left(\sqrt{5}-2\right) m+2 n}{2 \sqrt{5} m} & \frac{-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+\left(\sqrt{5}-2\right) m+2 n}{2 \sqrt{5} m} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-3\right) & \frac{-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+\left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{5} m} & \frac{\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+\left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{5} m} \\
 \frac{-\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}-2 n\right)-m}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & \frac{\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}-2 n\right)-m}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & -\frac{3 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} \\
 \frac{m-\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+2 n\right)}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & \frac{\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+2 n\right)+m}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & \frac{-\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} & \frac{-3 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m-2 n}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}} \\
\end{array}
\right).$$</sub>

Now we note that for large $m,n$ of order $1/\epsilon$, the matrix $M_0$ is of order $1/\epsilon$ while the matrix $M_1$ is of order unity. We can therefore perform perturbation theory in the small parameter $\epsilon$.

Let me first look at the positive eigenvalues. To zeroth order these are given by $\beta_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(\pm \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}+m+2 n\right)$. To first order these are the $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$ diagonal elements of $M_0+M_1$, which gives the two positive eigenvalues
$$\beta_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(m+2 n\pm\sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}\right)\pm\frac{m-2 n
\mp 3 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}}{2 \sqrt{m^2+4 n^2}}.$$
This expression for the positive eigenvalues is quite accurate, see the plot for $m=n$, where the exact expressions (red and green lines) are almost indistinguishable from the perturbative result (blue and orange).

[image]

Now for the negative eigenvalues. To first order these are given by the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ diagonal elements of $M_0+M_1$, equal to
$$\alpha_1=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-3\right)=-2.618,\;\;\alpha_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)=-0.382.$$

Here is the plot for $m=n$, again red and green is exact, blue and orange the perturbative result.

[image]

So to first order in $\epsilon$ one has $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=-3$. The challenge is to prove that higher order corrections are negative. Incidentally, the restriction to integer $m,n$ does not seem to play any role (in the plot $m=n$ is varied continuously).

Comment: I am thankful for such a detailed explanation, I would be grateful if you could explain how you obtained the two matrices $M_0,M_1$

Comment: this is the usual way one does perturbation theory: you first look only at the elements of $M$ that grow with increasing $m,n$, that matrix can be diagonalized by $S$ and that gives $M_0$; then what is left is a correction $M_1$, so $S^{-1}MS=M_0+M_1$.

Comment: I was just wondering if this can be done with any bounds that exist on smallest and second  smallest eigenvalue of a matrix, it just came to my mind so I thought of sharing with you

Comment: Is there any other way we can prove this fact that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<-3$ without using numerical mathematics

Comment: just for my information: why do you insist on this inequality, isn't the knowledge of the eigenvalues themselves of interest? as you can see the perturbative results are quite accurate.

Comment: Yes, but finding the eigenvalues requires an approximation whereas finding the bound is quite sharp, and frankly speaking I never did perturbation theory, so I am not aware of this concept

Comment: If we could successfully prove it, then we won't require to use any complex calculations, so I asked you if it can be proved as is done in pure Mathematics, but I really appreciate the hard work you are putting in for me and I thank you for that.

Comment: How about the case $n=m^2$?

Comment: @user64494 --- $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are independent of $n,m$, equal to $-\tfrac{1}{2}(3\pm\sqrt 5)$, when both $n$ and $m$ are $\gg 1$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker; I had one question, how can we prove that $\alpha_1-\alpha_2<-3$ when we are in higher order. You did here the approximation for $0$ and $1$ order, isn't it? or am I missing something

Comment: please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: @Math_Freak -- a higher order calculation will become increasingly complex; as a motivation, it would help if you would disclose why an accurate  expression for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ is not sufficient for your purpose, and you insist on the inequality $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<-3$ --- when for large $n,m$ this inequality becomes an equality; why is the equality not enough?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker; how would we get an accurate expression of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$? I thought giving an upper bound would be easier than finding the exact eigenvalues, so I insisted on the bound

Comment: an upper bound doesn't tell you much about the actual value of the eigenvalues; the perturbation expansion gives you $\alpha_{1,2}=-\tfrac{1}{2}(3\pm\sqrt 5)$ plus corrections of order $(m^2+n^2)^{-1/2}$; if you wish, you can go one order higher and have a correction of order $(m^2+n^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker; even if I go one order higher and prove it, how will I show that it is true for all other dimensions? I am confused, can you please help

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of Mathematica. First, the function $f(m,n)$ finds the sum of  the negative eigenvalues of the matrix under consideration. Second, we numerically find the maximum value of $f(x,y)$ over the integers greater than or equal to $4$ with relative error $10^{-3}$. The results are as follows.

```
f[m_, n_] := Total[Map[Min[0, #] &, 
Eigenvalues[{{0, m - 1, 2, n - 1}, {1, m - 2, 1, n - 1}, {2, m - 1,
0, 2 n - 2}, {1, m - 1, 2, 2 n - 4}}] // N]]
NMaximize[{f[x, y],   x >= 4 && y >= 4 && x \[Element] Integers && y \[Element] Integers}, 
{x, y}, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

$$\{-3.,\{x\to 12854143321479777526031848555457428151289960383333269504,y\to 1051298338250582241682620486779844006807195121763745792\}\} $$
Edit. A typo in the code for the matrix under consideration.

Comment: For example, `n = 61; m = 56; 
Eigenvalues[{{0, m - 1, 2, n - 1}, {1, m - 2, 1, n - 1}, {2, m - 1, 0,
     2 n - 2}, {1, m - 1, 2, 2 n - 2}}] // N` performs $\{155.857,21.113,-2.58165,-0.388454\}$.

Comment: but $-2.67282$ is greater than $-3$, so you are saying the claim of the OP is false? the value for $m$ where this sum is reached seems so astronomically large, it looks suspiciously like an issue of too little numerical accuracy

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Yes, `f[62605783003825957106601552641839576616084246664423713800192, 4]` produces $-2.67282$ and `m = 62605783003825957106601552641839576616084246664423713800192; n =
  4;Eigenvalues[{{0, m - 1, 2, n - 1}, {1, m - 2, 1, n - 1}, {2, m - 1, 0,
     2 n - 2}, {1, m - 1, 2, 2 n - 2}}] // N` results in $\{155.857,21.113,-2.58165,-0.388454\}$.

Comment: the matrix of the OP has $2(n-2)$ and not $2n-2$ as in your Mathematica code

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @user64494; thanks for your efforts, but the problem needs to be proved mathematically and not through any software like Mathematica

Comment: @CarloBeenakker; is there any trick by which it can be proved mathematically without using any numerical computation

Comment: @Math_Freak: Numeric mathis apart of math, like or dislike it,

Comment: @user64494; I understand that but the question has to be done without numeric, it needs to be proved.